# How to create a command that has a parameter

Tags: macros, overleaf

I would like to create a my limits a certain way.

This is the way i write a limit rifght now :

```
\underset{x \to x_0}\lim f(x) = \ell

How could I make it like \Lim{x \to \x_0} f(x) = \ell
So this would be equivlane to 
\underset{x \to x_0}\lim f(x) = \ell
```

But also make it work for another number number or to infinity such as :

`\Lim{n \to \infty} f(x) = \ell` and this equivalent to ```
\underset{n \to \infty}\lim f(x) = \ell

Comment: Erh, why? `\lim_{x\to x_0}` already places the limit under it in displayed math, In text math the linit should never be placed under `lim`

Comment: I would like to create a command so instead of using undefset it does it automaticly. Because rn idk how to change if my variable is x n z or anything.

Comment: Search for `\newcommand`

Comment: Yes i thought of \newcommand but i'am asking help to create it.

Comment: Have you tried `$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}$`? Is the presence of the underscore character between `\lim\limits` and `{x\to x_0}` bothering you?

Comment: Why do you want to use `\underset`? The `\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)` isn't sufficient?

Comment: I believe, `OP` wants to know how to define a new command

Comment: Yes I want to define a new command

Comment: You can define `\def\Lim{\lim\limits_}`

Comment: No, `\def` is TeX primitive, no plain TeX command. `\limits` is TeX primitive too.

Comment: why do you want a command? you do not need underset , `\Lim{n \to \infty} f(x) = \ell`  is no easier to write than `\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x) = \ell`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because when i write them inline, my n to infinty doesn't go under the limit it goes to the bottom right and it is really ugly...

Comment: you could redefine `\lim` to use `\limits`, no need for `\underset` but the whole point of inline as opposed to display math is to fit the expression inline without increasing basline spacing, so this destroys that fundamental design aim.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to `TeX.SE`

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{#1} and the usage is \test{print test}
```

You have to pass the number of arguments in square brackets and inside parenthesis, have to mention the style of arguments, e.g.,

```
\newcommand{\testing}[2]{\textit{#1}\quad \textbf{#2}} and the usage is \testing{this}{is for test}
```

Hope this helps you...

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


\newcommand{\Limm}[1]{\underset{#1}{\lim}}

$\Limm{Test}$

\vspace{3pc}

%%Another Method
\newcommand{\limm}[1]{\lim\limits_{#1}}

$\limm{Test}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this but it does'nt compile : ```\newcommand{\Limm}[1]{\underset{{#1}{\lim}}}```